# How can i get the body response with morgan

Tags: node.js, express, morgan

I am trying to get body response with morgan, this is my code:

```
 morgan.token('request-body', (req, res) => {
    return res.body && (res.body && `\n## RESPONSE ##  ${JSON.stringify(req.body)}\n` || "{}\n")
});

 app.use(morgan(':request-body'));
```

but always, the body response is empty

This is my app.js

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var morgan = require('morgan')

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(morgan())
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try  with [morgan-body](https://www.npmjs.com/package/morgan-body)

```
import morganBody from 'morgan-body';
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';

const app = express();

// must parse body before morganBody as body will be logged
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// hook morganBody to express app
morganBody(app);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try it : `app.use(morgan('combined'))`

Comment: @le-qaung, The standart combined format is ":remote-addr - :remote-user [:date[clf]] ":method :url HTTP/:http-version" :status :res[content-length] ":referrer" ":user-agent", but i need res.body

Comment: You can use `express-winston` and  config you search `npm express-winston` for more detail